# form.submit not working after applying a class for datetimepicker in jquery Jeditable

Tags: jquery, jeditable

On applying class in editable, datepicker appears and selected value is displaying in textbox. but the script form.submit is not working in editable.js

Script in jeditable is as follows :

```
    $.editable = {
    types: {
    defaults: {
    element : function(settings, original) {
        var input = $('<input type="hidden"></input>');                
        $(this).append(input);
        return(input);
    },

    text: {
    element : function(settings, original) { 
        var input = $('<input />');
        if (settings.width  != 'none') { input.attr('width', settings.width);  }
        if (settings.height != 'none') { input.attr('height', settings.height); }
        if (settings.style  != 'none') { input.attr('style', "width:100%;border:1px solid #ccc;"); }

        input.attr('autocomplete','off');

        if ( typeof settings.class !== 'undefined' && settings.class == 'datePickClass' ) {
                  input.attr('class','datePickClass');  

          $(input).datetimepicker({
            datepicker:true,
            format:'Y-m-d H:i:s',
            step:5
          });                                         
                }

        $(this).append(input);
        return(input);
    }
    },

    addInputType: function(name, input) {
     $.editable.types[name] = input;
    }
    };
```

In js file :

```
    $(".dateEdit").editable(apiUrl, {     
  indicator : "<img src='images/close-icon-one.png'>",
      tooltip   : "",      
      functionName : "updateEachField" ,
      table : "audits",
      token : accessToken,
      userId : loggedInUser,
      conditionField : 'audit_id',
      class:'datePickClass'
    });
```